# ASP.NET ImageButton onclick javascript not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a bunch of very similar pages on my site, and on many of them, I have ImageButtons that remove or delete some sort of grid/tree entry. For all of those, I want to tie a javascript that essentially pops up a "Do you really want to delete x" dialog window.

It's working fine on almost every page, but on this particular one, the script never fires. When inspecting the button, I see the onclick event corretly listed. But upon clicking the button, I get the following console error on the client:

```
ReferenceError: removeButtonConfirmation is not defined
```

And nothing else happens.

The button in the .ascx file:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="DeleteColumn">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="DeleteButton" CommandName="Delete" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

The code behind:

```
var deleteButton = item["DeleteColumn"].FindControl("DeleteButton") as ImageButton;
deleteButton.ImageUrl = UrlHelper.SharedImage("delete2.png");
deleteButton.ToolTip = SiteTextResources.Administration_ShippingManager_Remove;
var onclickValue = String.Format("return removeButtonConfirmation('{0}');", "Are you sure you want to delete this?");
 deleteButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", onclickValue);
```

The js:

```
function removeButtonConfirmation(message) {
    var result = window.confirm(message);
    if (result)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding onclick attribute use OnClientClick property of ImageButton like following

Replace you following code behind line

```
var onclickValue = String.Format("return removeButtonConfirmation('{0}');", "Are you sure you want to delete this?");
 deleteButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", onclickValue);
```

With this

```
deleteButton.OnClientClick = String.Format("return removeButtonConfirmation('{0}');", "Are you sure you want to delete this?");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same result with this.